# What is an algorithm to enumerate lambda terms?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

What is an algorithm that will enumerate expressions for the lambda calculus by order of length? For example, `(λx.x), (λx.(x x)), (λx.(λy.x))` and so on?

Comment: How do you define length?

Comment: @KristopherMicinski any order will do it, I did not mean to be strict on this word. I just wanted to avoid obvious disasters such as generating `(λx.(λy.(λz.((z x) (y x) x y y))))` before `(λx.λy.y)`, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As length I would choose the number of `T`-expansions ("depth") in this BNF of (untyped) lambda expressions:

```
V ::= x | y
T ::= V    | 
      λV.T |
      (T T)
```

In python you can define a generator following the above generation rules for given variables and a given depth like this:

```
def lBNF(vars, depth):
  if depth == 1:
    for var in vars:
      yield var
  elif depth > 1:
    for var in vars:
      for lTerm in lBNF(vars,depth-1):
        yield 'l%s.%s' % (var,lTerm)
    for i in range(1,depth):
      for lTerm1 in lBNF(vars,i):
        for lTerm2 in lBNF(vars,depth-i):
          yield '(%s %s)' % (lTerm1,lTerm2)
```

Now you can enumerate the lambda terms for/up to a given depth:

```
vars = ['x','y']
for i in range(1,5):
  for lTerm in lBNF(vars,i):
    print lTerm
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Is it possible to modify it so it generates only closed terms, using bruijn indices?

Comment: @viclib you mean that there are no unbound variables? (never heard of bruijn indices) That would require some postprocessing - or some other smart adaption ...

Comment: Uh huh, it is just a way to throw the strings of. (λ(λ(0 1))) - here, 0 is bound to the second λ and 1 is bound to the fist.

Answer (score 1):

See https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2610, page 5. Here is some example code:

```
from itertools import chain, count
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def terms(size, level=0):
    if size == 0:
        return tuple(range(level))
    else:
        abstractions = (
            ('abs', term)
            for term in terms(size - 1, level + 1)
        )
        applications = (
            ('app', term1, term2)
            for i in range(size)
            for term1 in terms(i, level)
            for term2 in terms(size - 1 - i, level)
        )
        return tuple(chain(abstractions, applications))

def string(term):
    if isinstance(term, tuple):
        if term[0] == 'abs':
            return '(λ {})'.format(string(term[1]))
        elif term[0] == 'app':
            return '({} {})'.format(string(term[1]), string(term[2]))
    else:
        return term

for size in count():
    print('{} terms of size {}'.format(len(terms(size)), size))
    for term in terms(size):
        pass # input(string(term))
```

This outputs

```
0 terms of size 0
1 terms of size 1
3 terms of size 2
14 terms of size 3
82 terms of size 4
579 terms of size 5
4741 terms of size 6
43977 terms of size 7
454283 terms of size 8
```

and so on (i.e. [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A220894)).

Comment: You can also count by number of bits as in oeis.org/A333479